# Excel XML Newline in Cell

Tags: c#, excel, linq-to-xml

I am using LINQ to XML to create an [Excel XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140066%28office.10%29.aspx) file. I want to include newlines within the cells. Excel uses the `&#10;` literal to represent a new line. If I try to add this using an XText:

```
XText newlineElement = new XText( "Foo&#10;Bar" );
```

I get:

`Foo&amp;#10;Bar`

Which shows up in Excel as:

`Foo&#10;Bar`

Is there a way to write `&#10` to the XML file without doing a

```
String.Replace( "&amp;#10;", "&#10;" )
```

over the resulting file text?

**EDIT** Here is a code snippet showing how I create a row for the Excel document. I was avoiding it since it is a little messy. :) Let me know if more code would help, or if this just adds more confusion.

In this example, the `newlineElement` described above is represented by the only XText in the code sample.

```
const string CELL = "{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}Cell";
const string DATA = "{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}Data";
const string STYLE = "{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}StyleID";
const string TYPE= "{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}Type";   
const string HEIGHT = "{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}Height";
const string ROW = "{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}Row";
```

...

```
XElement rowElement = new XElement( Row,
                                    new XElement( CELL,
                                        new XAttribute( STYLE, "s0" ) ),
                                    new XElement( CELL,
                                        new XElement( DATA,
                                            new XText( description.Replace("\n", "&#10;") ), 
                                            new XAttribute( TYPE, "String" ) ),
                                        new XAttribute( STYLE, "sWrap" ) ),
                                    new XElement( CELL,
                                        new XAttribute( STYLE, "s0" ) ),
                                    new XAttribute( HEIGHT, height ) );
```

This produces:

```
  <ss:Row ss:Height="45">
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s0" />
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="sWrap">
      <ss:Data ss:Type="String">Foo&amp;#10;Bar</ss:Data>
    </ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="s0" />
  </ss:Row>
```

Thanks for the help thus far!

Comment: Believe it or not, this doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: Could you post some example code for how this is getting into the Excel file?

Comment: Basically, it would be nice to see some code showing how you're using the newlineElement object after you create it.

Answer (score 1):

insert the actual character into the string rather than the escape code - LINQ will handle the conversion for you.

**EDIT:**

Ok - this was completely wrong, but helped me to get something which (I think) works. If you want to embed something which would otherwise be escaped by the XML rendering, you need to embed it in a `CDATA` block. Check out [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949122/insert-text-node-to-xml-document-containing-xml) on C# and XML which tripped my memory.

Comment: I think you can use "\n" to insert inline.

Comment: I stand corrected - just tried myself also, same result... What an interesting irritation!

Comment: This partially worked! The .xml file contains the right characters; however, Excel still displays '&#10;' instead of the newline. :/

Comment: Have you tried inserting the actual newline character rather than the escape code? If you are entering the escape code in the CDATA block it will escape the escape, if you follow :-)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps, but the following code:

```
var newlineElement = new XText("Foo&#10;Bar");
Console.WriteLine(newlineElement);
Console.WriteLine(newlineElement.Value);
```

Produces this output:

`Foo$amp;#10;Bar`

`Foo&#10;Bar`

So, in your code that is using the `newlineElement` object, could you use the `.Value` property?